# For the dancing couples objective, does it have to be unique couples?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Regarding the objective to have "15 male and female couples dance in the living quarters", assuming I interrupt each dance before the couple heads to the back room, if the same distinct pair dances together multiple times, does each dance count against the running total, or must I pair unique couples together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no requirement for "unique dwellers" when completing 'dance' objectives.

I would personally streamline this objective by sending one of the dwellers to the next room once they started dancing, before sending them back in to wash and repeat.